# stack of blocks answers true if they are on top of each other

Tags: prolog

Define a stack of  blocks as on the picture:
Given the relations

on(b,a). 
on(c,b).
on(d,c).

Define a Prolog predicate above(Block2,Block1) that is true if Block2 is above Block1.

So I have:

```
on(b,a).
on(c,b).
on(d,c).
above(Block2,Block1):- on(X,Y).
```

But this code appears to be broken it answers true either way I need it to answer false if they are not on top of each other.

Comment: The singleton variable warnings are not to be ignored! What you have here is like an equation that reads "f(b1, b2) = x + y"--what does it mean? Use the same variables in the head and the body!

Comment: ok I'll give it a try

Comment: yea above(Block2,Block1):- on(Block2,Block1) works thanks!